# Lua - convert string to table

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I want to convert string text to table and this text must be divided on characters. Every character must be in separate value of table, for example:

- a="text"
- --converting string (a) to table (b)
- --show table (b)
- b={'t','e','x','t'}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use string.gsub function

```
t={}
str="text"
str:gsub(".",function(c) table.insert(t,c) end)
```

Comment: A Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes; not necessarily a character string. What a character is and what `gsub` et al do depend on the implementation. `local str = "СПАСИБО!"; str:gsub(".",function(c) print(c) end)` doesn't work out very well on my box's lua.

Comment: This only works if the pattern string contains one matching-pattern.  I.e. `str:gsub("(.)",function(c) table.insert(t,c) end)` works fine, but in `str:gsub("(.).(.)",function(c) table.insert(t,c) end)`, the second matching-pattern will be lost.  If `str="abcdef"`, first case assigns all 6 characters to `t{}`, but `t{}` gets only `a` and `d` in the second case

Answer (score 17):

Just index each symbol and put it at same position in table.

```
local str = "text"
local t = {}
for i = 1, #str do
    t[i] = str:sub(i, i)
end
```

Comment: thanks, it work. Sorry, I had already accepted another answer :C

Answer (score 4):

The builtin **string** library treats Lua strings as byte arrays.
An alternative that works on multibyte (Unicode) characters is the
[**unicode** library](https://github.com/LuaDist/slnunicode) that
originated in the Selene project.
Its main selling point is that it can be used as a drop-in replacement
for the string library, making most string operations “magically”
Unicode-capable.

If you prefer not to add third party dependencies your task can easily
be implemented using [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/).
Here is an example splitter:

```
local lpeg       = require "lpeg"
local C, Ct, R   = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.R
local lpegmatch  = lpeg.match

local split_utf8 do
  local utf8_x  = R"\128\191"
  local utf8_1  = R"\000\127"
  local utf8_2  = R"\194\223" * utf8_x
  local utf8_3  = R"\224\239" * utf8_x * utf8_x
  local utf8_4  = R"\240\244" * utf8_x * utf8_x * utf8_x
  local utf8    = utf8_1 + utf8_2 + utf8_3 + utf8_4
  local split   = Ct (C (utf8)^0) * -1

  split_utf8 = function (str)
    str = str and tostring (str)
    if not str then return end
    return lpegmatch (split, str)
  end
end
```

This snippet defines the function `split_utf8()` that creates a table
of UTF8 characters (as Lua strings), but returns `nil` if the string
is not a valid UTF sequence.
You can run this test code:

```
tests = {
  en = [[Lua (/ˈluːə/ LOO-ə, from Portuguese: lua [ˈlu.(w)ɐ] meaning moon; ]]
    .. [[explicitly not "LUA"[1]) is a lightweight multi-paradigm programming ]]
    .. [[language designed as a scripting language with "extensible ]]
    .. [[semantics" as a primary goal.]],
  ru = [[Lua ([лу́а], порт. «луна») — интерпретируемый язык программирования, ]]
    .. [[разработанный подразделением Tecgraf Католического университета ]]
    .. [[Рио-де-Жанейро.]],
  gr = [[Η Lua είναι μια ελαφρή προστακτική γλώσσα προγραμματισμού, που ]]
    .. [[σχεδιάστηκε σαν γλώσσα σεναρίων με κύριο σκοπό τη δυνατότητα ]]
    .. [[επέκτασης της σημασιολογίας της.]],
  XX = ">\255< invalid"
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local limit = 14
for lang, str in next, tests do
  io.write "\n"
  io.write (string.format ("<%s %3d> ->", lang, #str))
  local chars = split_utf8 (str)
  if not chars then
    io.write " INVALID!"
  else
    io.write (string.format (" <%3d>", #chars))
    for i = 1, #chars > limit and limit or #chars do
      io.write (string.format (" %q", chars [i]))
    end
  end
end
io.write "\n"
```

Btw., building a table with LPeg is significantly faster than calling
`table.insert()` repeatedly.
Here are stats for splitting the whole of Gogol’s *Dead Souls* (in
Russian, 1023814 bytes raw, 571395 characters UTF) on my machine:

```
library        method                time in ms
string         table.insert()        380
string         t [#t + 1] = c        310
string         gmatch & for loop     280
slnunicode     table.insert()        220
slnunicode     t [#t + 1] = c        200
slnunicode     gmatch & for loop     170
lpeg           Ct (C (...))           70
```

Answer (score 2):

You can below code to achieve this easily.

```lua
t = {}
str = "text"

for i=1, string.len(str) do
  t[i]= (string.sub(str,i,i))
end

for k , v in pairs(t) do
  print(k,v)
end

-- 1    t
-- 2    e
-- 3    x
-- 4    t
```

Using `string.sub`

```lua
string.sub(s, i [, j])
```

Return a substring of the string passed. The substring starts at i. If the third argument j is not given, the substring will end at the end of the string. If the third argument is given, the substring ends at and includes j.