# Lua: How do I access a string value as an array (or table)?

Tags: arrays, string, lua

I was wondering how I use a string value as an array in Lua. I do know how to use it in languages like C#, but I don't know how to do it in Lua.

Comment: Is you goal to access individual characters or character spans of the string?

Comment: Show us the equivalent C# code that you're trying to accomplish in lua.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua - convert string to table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423406/lua-convert-string-to-table)

Comment: To get single character at position i (1-based), use `str:sub(i,i)`. The is no opposite operation (to modify single character inside a string), as Lua strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

`string.sub(yourString,i,j)` or just `sub(yourString,i,j)` where `i = j` to get just one character in the string. Remember that Lua is 1-indexed, not 0-indexed like C#. Have a look at the [Lua string documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the String metatable and change the metamethod __index to return the character on a given position... the code below does exactly that.

```
getmetatable('').__index = function(str,i) return string.sub(str,i,i) end
--example
string = "dog"
print(string[3])
-- Output: g
```

Comment: I tried to use the __newindex to make it read/write, but turn out that the first argument in the function is a string, and thus is passed by copy... should it got passed by reference it would be possible to change it.